# Capture screenshot of alert

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver

I have used the below code to take screenshot of the application after pop up appears.

```java
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
File scrFile= ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("G:\\Screens\\sc1.jpg"));
String alertMsg = alert.getText();
System.out.println(alertMsg);
alert.accept();
```

But it is throwing this exception

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException:Modal dialog present: Assessment Name already Exist.

But the code works fine if I remove the screenshot procedures.

Comment: Hey Nick the link you have given as duplicate is also the same link as that of my question. Only one question exists

Comment: Thanks @AndersLindén

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always get the screenshot of entire page using Robot. I just tried it out, this code is working:

```
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptalert.php");
}

@Test
public void bla() throws AWTException, IOException {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"button\"]"));
    // Trigger the alert
    element.click();
    BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
    ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("c:\\localdev\\bla.png"));
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
}
```

Comment: But the problem with this method is that if we are performing the test in background then the actual screen which is active will be captured.

Comment: I run selenium on Linux with virtual display and it works for me

Answer (score 5):

You have to handle the alert before you take a screenshot... you can read about it more here
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4412

Comment: So it it no possible to take screenshot of the alert

Comment: @Praveen, you do not provide any solution to the problem.