# Take snapshot of JS alert with Selenium

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, popup, snapshot

I saw only old messages saying it is not possible yet, but did not find recent (from the last year) with a way to do it.

I know how to take snapshot in Selenium (I am using C#)

I know how to accept/cancel JS popup.

But when I wish to take a snapshot of the JS popup, it is being accepted and there is no image.

Is there a recent way?

Comment: You can get the screenshot of entire page using Robot.

Comment: Hi there. I am not familiar with Robot. Can you send a link/Sample?
@Akzy

Comment: Checkout [https://stackoverflow.com/a/21673179/11863448]