How to take full page screenshot while handling UnhandledAlertException
I have some test case which I am executing and after that I am taking screenshot. Now In case of Alert is present I am taking full page screenshot.
I am using Robot for taking full page screenshot. The problem which I am facing while taking full page screenshot is it is taking my system screenshot instead of the application where I am executing.
Here is my code of taking screenshot.
protected void getScreenshot(String path ) {
    try {
     
      byte[] screenshot = screenshotService.takeScreenshot();
      screenshotService.saveBytesArrayToFile(path, screenshot);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.debug("UnhandledAlertException occurred during screenshot capture, using Robot to take the screenshot");
      RobotService robotService = new RobotService();
      BufferedImage screenshot = robotService.takeScreenShot();
      screenshotService.saveBufferedImageToFile(path, screenshot);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      log.error("Exception", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }

for taking normal screenshot screenshotService.takeScreenshot();
public byte[] takeScreenshot() throws UnhandledAlertException {
    RemoteWebDriver driver = DriverManager.getRemoteWebDriver();
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
  }

for taking robot screenshot robotService.takeScreenshot();
public BufferedImage takeScreenShot() {
    try {
      Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        return new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
  }

How in this case how should I handle UnhandledAlertException

Are you talking about handling UnhandledAlertException in robotService.takeScreenshot();?

Do you have code example to reproduce this? Looking for main method to run this code on local.

@AnishB. No when I am running this screenshotService.takeScreenshot(); I am getting UnhandledAlertException  as you see in code so to manage that I want to take full page screenshot by using  robotService.takeScreenShot(); But here it is capturing screenshot of my system window not of application

Ok. Got it. Please provide minimum code example to reproduce this.

@AnishB. Let me see if I can prepare code as kinda complex. Only thing is while caputring the screenshot I have alert on the page so it is throwing UnhandledAlertException  which I am trying to cover from  robotService.takeScreenShot();

Ok. Let me know when you will create the reproduceable code for testing. Meanwhile I'm checking on my side.

@AnishB. My problem is the first comment of the accepted Answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21670361/capture-screenshot-of-alert

Not an answer, but unhandled alert exception should only be thrown during a screenshot of a specific element.  Screenshot of full page using driver should never throw that.  (not sure if the screenshot would include the alert... )  You might try using another driver if it's throwing with posted code.  (I know IE driver used to be great for capturing full page screenshots... not just in viewport content)

in the question you linked to their call to driver.switchTo is throwing that.  (or at least that's what the W3C specs say... switchTo will check for any unhandled prompts and throw if they exist... )

@browsermator first it will be throw the unhandled alert exception because there is alert in page and that is another window. To cover i am taking screenshot with Robot which will take screenshot of whole window. Now let say If I am running in cloud env in that case we don't know what window is open because Robot will only take screenshot of open window. Not the application what we are running.

Take Screenshot should not check for unhandled prompts.  Only when calling that on an element (Take Element Screenshot) should it do that check and throw if they are there.  You can see the spec here: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver2/#take-screenshot
